# SharePoint 2010 Multi Tenant - I need Excel Services

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel-services, multi-tenancy

We are running SP in Multi-Tenant mode for a few small clients. I need Excel services enabled for two of the tenants. What options do I have and how do I do it?

I have been looking at documentation but SP2010 Multi Tenant documents are few and far between.

Answer (score 0):

The following services do not store tenant data, and do not support Partition Mode:

- State
- Access Database
- Visio Graphics
- Word Viewing
- PowerPoint
- Excel Calculation
  http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010mt1.aspx
  Check this diagram for more infor:
  http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/5/4/7546DDD5-C8B3-46F0-8087-8A7A37F739E6/Hosting_SharePointProducts2010.pdf

when you configure Excel Services (no partitioning options are available) it does appear to honour subscriptions in the configuration, ie you can use a tenanted Secure Store to create Excel Services Application IDs, however the catch is that it will only talk to the Secure Store in the Default proxy group!

http://nearbaseline.com/blog/2011/01/excel-services-in-a-multi-tenanted-environment/